# Best Way to Check In Three Events at Once?

Tags: civievent

So here is the scenario

- Three events happening at same time
- Had to setup 3 different registration pages because only certain people were invited to certain things.
- When we check people in, we want to make sure we have them checked in for all events they are registered for.
- we are using QR code check in but are open to other options.
- We also want to be able to identify VIPs when checking them in

Here are a couple ideas I had

- Create a price set with all the RSVP options and move all the RSVP's to a new event and make sure all the right price set options are chosen. This way when we use QR code check in, it will show all the correct options to the person checking them in. We would be managing RSVP's in two places, but it would streamline check in.
- Create a new event for another scenario. Everyone is attending event B, but some people are attending event A,B,&C
- Create VIP as a participant role.

Wordpress and Civi 5.48

Answer (score 1):

These are all good thoughts.

The easiest approach, if starting from scratch, would be to have one "umbrella" event and the price sets dictate access to the other events.

Given your current situation - since everyone is attending event B, I would probably just use QR check-in on that event, and after everything was over, create a group of all attendees in event B.  Then search for event A (and C) attendees in the group and update their participant status in bulk.

If you need this done in near real-time, you could use SQL Tasks to automate this, but that's more technical.

I think "VIP" as a participant role makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Can you restrict price set options to only show up on certain events? Thats a key challenge as not all people going to B can go to A or C.

Answer (score 1):

If this is useful, i can dig it out for you. We did an extension that adds a custom field to an Event. If you then put another Event ID (for the 'parent' event) in to this field on the 'child event' then anyone registering for the 'parent' event gets registered for any/all 'child' events.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.multipleeventreg
I'll give it a try, even if not for this event, thanks so much.

Ideally we would want a way for people checking guests in to easily see what other events they are registered for.

Comment: ah yep. looks like the client site still has the original and hence wasn't aware we had published.

Comment: "Set A as Parent Event, so registering for A also registers them for B and C." For those registering only for B, just point them to rego page for B instead of A

Comment: What about those only registering for C and B - would we make that a parent event for B too? Can you have two parents?

Comment: no doesn't offer option of having 2 parents

Answer (score 1):

To register participants for a series of events, we use the [Event Additional Signup Extension](https://aghstrategies.com/event-additional-signup-extension/), which can be found in the extensions manager of CiviCRM.

I think it covers your basic requirements: Just set up price sets and link the appropriate option to the additional event(s) signup.